# pop up with editable text in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, popup

I want to give the privilage for the user to rename a file. For that When the user clicks on menu item 'rename'a  pop up dialogue with and editable text box should show up with 'ok' and 'cancel' buttons? How can i implement it? Pls share the code if there are any.

Br,
Jinu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `InputPrompt` from the [Coding4fun Tookit](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/)

The documentation is available on Codeplex: http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=InputPrompt&referringTitle=Documentation

Calling it is straightforward:

```
var input = new InputPrompt();
input.Completed += InputCompleted;
input.Title = "Rename file";
input.Message = "Enter a new name for the file:";
input.Show();
```

Then you just have to retrieve the value in the callback:

```
private void InputCompleted(object sender, PopUpEventArgs<object, PopUpResult> e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.Instead of using a third party library, Can i use some classes from the silverlite itself?

Comment: You sure can. Feel free to build your own InputPrompt using, for instance, the `Popup` control.